# PowerApps compare Table values to Text

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

I have a collection with job titles and question id's called `colFunctions`. I want to compare the job titles in the collection to a single known job title (a text value) and return a list of question id's.

[image]

So for the function Jr. System Administrator I want to get a list with ID's of Q01 and Q03, but not Q02.

I have this so far, but it says I can't compare a table to a text value. How can I overcome this?

```
ClearCollect(
    colMatchedFunction,
    Filter(colFunctions,Function = Office365Users.UserProfileV2(galleryDirectReports.Selected.userPrincipalName).jobTitle).QuestionID
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Function is a text column in SharePoint, or a multi-select choice column? If it is a text column, you can use the [`in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/operators#in-and-exactin-operators), which can check if a the text contains the given id:

```
ClearCollect(
  colMatchedFunction,
  Filter(
    colFunctions,
    Office365Users.UserProfileV2(galleryDirectReports.Selected.userPrincipalName).jobTitle).QuestionID in Function 
));
```

In a multi-select choice column, you can still use the in operator, this time to check if a value belongs to a table, checking it against the 'Value' property of the multi-select column (which returns the text value represented by the choice):

```
ClearCollect(
  colMatchedFunction,
  Filter(
    colFunctions,
    Office365Users.UserProfileV2(galleryDirectReports.Selected.UserPrincipalName).jobTitle
        in Function.Value
));
```

Comment: Hi carlosfigueira, thx for the answer. It's a multi-select column. Would that require a different approach?

Comment: Updated the answer with the option for a multi-select choice column.

Comment: Ah, in Function.Value. Thank you! You learned me a valuable trick about working with Tables.